# Popping up form from DLL on same screen as calling form

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, dll

I Have a DLL:   (MessageBox.DLL)
This DLL has a form which looks just like a messagebox.

The msgbox has similar parameter as original messagebox,

```vb
myMsgBox("TEXT HERE")
```

but the problem is that, if there are multiple screens, it sometimes pops up on the wrong screen

I would like to get the Calling form as a reference, without passing as parameter like so

```vb
Sub myMsgBox(ByVal MsgText As String) 
     formMsgbox.mainText = MsgText
     formMsgbox.Show()
End Sub
```

What I would like to do is Reference the original form like so

```vb
Sub myMsgBox(ByVal MsgText As String) 
     formMsgbox.mainText = MsgText
     formMsgbox.size = new size (me.parent.size.x / 2, me.parent.size.y / 2)
     Dim Current_Screen As Screen = Screen.FromControl(me.parent)
     If Current_Screen.Primary = False Then
         Dim HCenter = Current_Screen.Bounds.Left + _
         (((Current_Screen.Bounds.Right - Current_Screen.Bounds.Left) / 2) - ((formMsgbox.Width) / 2))
         Dim VCenter = (Current_Screen.Bounds.Bottom / 2) - ((formMsgbox.Height) / 2)
         formMsgbox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
         formMsgbox.Location = New Point(HCenter, VCenter)
     Else
         formMsgbox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
     End If
     formMsgbox.Show()
End Sub
```

Obviously, I can do this if I pass Form every time, But trying to avoid that.

I would like it to work just like original Microsoft Messagebox, where you don't pass the parent, it gets it by itself.

Thank in advance

Comment: Me.Parent is unlikely to be the one you had in mind.  Consider Form.ActiveForm, like MsgBox() does.  If it *must* be the "calling form" then you must add an extra argument.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, thats what i was looking for   (Form.Activeform) . Please post that as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Just show us what you ended up doing in your own post and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up calling the active form by using

```vb
Form.ActiveForm
```

So this now works as intended:

```vb
Sub myMsgBox(ByVal MsgText As String) 
     Dim f as Form.ActiveForm
     formMsgbox.mainText = MsgText
     formMsgbox.size = new size (f.size.x / 2, f.size.y / 2)
     Dim Current_Screen As Screen = Screen.FromControl(f)
     If Current_Screen.Primary = False Then
         Dim HCenter = Current_Screen.Bounds.Left + _
         (((Current_Screen.Bounds.Right - Current_Screen.Bounds.Left) / 2) - ((formMsgbox.Width) / 2))
         Dim VCenter = (Current_Screen.Bounds.Bottom / 2) - ((formMsgbox.Height) / 2)
         formMsgbox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
         formMsgbox.Location = New Point(HCenter, VCenter)
     Else
         formMsgbox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
     End If
     formMsgbox.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If getting the *calling form* is a requirement then you must add another parameter. To simplify it a bit further I would turn it into an [**extension method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods):

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub myMsgBox(ByVal TargetForm As Form, ByVal MsgText As String)
        formMsgbox.mainText = MsgText
        formMsgbox.Size = New Size(TargetForm.Width / 2, TargetForm.Height / 2)
        Dim Current_Screen As Screen = Screen.FromControl(TargetForm)

        ...the rest of your code...
    End Sub
End Module
```

Then you can use it like this:

```vb
Me.myMsgBox("Hello World!")
```